# Connect landline phone to pc and retrieve number of incoming call

Tags: php, e-commerce, telephony

I have made a simple php application which searches the details of people by inputting their phone number in the application. Now I want to extend its functionality that my landline phone is connected to my pc and whenever a call comes then the php application should fetch details of the related incoming number from database and display it. Now to implement this I need to get the number of that incoming call.

How can I connect landline to my pc? (I think a phone modem will be required but I am not sure.)
How can I get the number of that incoming call?

Answer (score 0):

If the landphone is connected to the Server on which PHP resides, then ask PHP to read log files generated by asterisk (if you are using Asterisk on a Linux server to handle the incoming calls). No idea about other Operating Systems or solutions.

Comment: Also check mgetty. It should also log calls to a modem (but cannot answer it). Should be more easier than Asterisk. But I think it cannot differentiate whether the call was picked up or not. Please explore. A reply is highly appreciated.

Another option is asking the customer to install a digital EPABX that has a web interface. (IP_Address:port_number will show call logs in CSV format). I have seen such an EPABX in a client site, but unfortunately, I didn't get that order to explore.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Sunish ... I will check with both the options .... for time being I will be checking with mgetty thing

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't have access to hardware for security issues. So you can't know if there's an incoming call.

Comment: it may be possible in java or not.  or tell me any other language